# lines not matching up in C3JS

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I am using C3JS and im trying to get my lines to align. if you look at both of the lines they are both on 0 for the first 10 months but despite that there is a gap between the 2. I have tried setting the min value to zero but that just messed up the graph. Is possible to display them together for the baseline 0.

[image]

Comment: Can we see your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks but i actually figured it out. it was caused by padding on the y2 axis and it was not obvious because the y2 axis was being displayed as a whole number(int). The padding was 10% (0.3) and thus the black line is at the zero mark - it just didn't look that way.